# The selectedBackgroundView modifies the contentView subviews

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm using a custom `backgroundView` and `selectedBackgroundView` for a `UITableViewCell` subclass. These cells are in a grouped table, so I'm setting the background and selected background as `UIImageView`s based on the cell's row in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

The problem I'm having is that when the cell is selected, its `selectedBackgroundView` modifies the contents of the `contentView`. For example, after selecting and/or highlighting a cell, the `UILabel` in the `contentView` has its `backgroundColor` changes and the `UIView` being used as a cell separator is not visible.

Before selection:
[image: Before selection/highlight]
After selection:
[image: After selection/highlight]

I don't see this behavior documented anywhere. Is there something I need to do to prevent this? Is there a different approach to showing cell selection/highlighting that I should take to prevent this?

- Note: Since it's a grouped table view, I set a different `backgroundView`s and `selectedBackgroundView`s with `UIImageView`s to account for the rounded corners on the top and bottom cells in the section in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, but I have the same problem when using the default `UITableViewSelectionStyleBlue`.

Edit 1:

Per an0's answer, I overrode `setHighlighted:animated:`. I'm not sure how reliable the implementation is, but this approach worked to maintain the `highlighted` and `backgroundColor` properties of the subviews:

```
NSArray *recursiveAllSubviews = [self recursiveValueForKey:@"subviews"]; // Uses MTRecursiveKVC Cocoapod
NSArray *backgroundColors = [recursiveAllSubviews valueForKey:@"backgroundColor"];
[super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
if (highlighted) {
    [recursiveAllSubviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView *view, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){
        if ([view respondsToSelector:@selector(setHighlighted:)]) {
            [view setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"highlighted"];
        }
        id possiblyNull = [backgroundColors objectAtIndex:index];
        if (possiblyNull != [NSNull null]) {
            view.backgroundColor = possiblyNull;
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Ah, this is probably related to "The content is selected automatically if the subview implements (if appropriate) the accessor methods for the highlighted property."

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`UITableViewCell` does two things automatically when highlighted/selected:

1. Set all its subviews' `backgroundColor` to clear color(transparent).
2. Highlight all subviews that can be highlighted, for example, `UIImageView`.

To prevent the first problem, you have to override these two methods in your `UITableViewCell` subclass:

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
    if (highlighted) {
        // Recover backgroundColor of subviews.
    }
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    if (selected) {
        // Recover backgroundColor of subviews.
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. My cell separator was implemented using the `backgroundColor` property so that explains why it disappeared as well.

Comment: I could guess that as well because I did similar things:)

Comment: If I want to stop the behavior of 1. and 2., am I best off overriding the `setHighlighted:animated:` and `setSelected:animated:` methods, not calling super, and implementing the methods myself? Unless there's a good way to do the 'recover backgroundColor` step that you alluded to.

Comment: Ok, I came up with a solution and added the code to my question.

Comment: Clear and concise. Good answer.

Comment: I came here looking for a solution to a different but related problem, but your answer and @MaxGabriel's comment clarified that my *real* problem was the view background's being made transparent. Thanks!

Comment: UIButton is not highlighted when cell is selected. I think subviews other than UIControl are highlighted, not all of them.

Comment: It works, but it still missing during pop back to tableViewController. Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

set `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`
and override

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated {
  if(highlighted) {
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = colorYouWantWhenHighlighted;
  } else {
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = colorYouWantWhenUnhighlighted;
  }
}
```

Comment: I did something similar to this, but instead of overriding a method (would required a new class, etc), I just changed the cell background  manually at tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:.

Comment: I assume when you tap on the cell, the app takes you to the next screen right away. I doubt your method works for highlight state(for example, put your finger down on the cell and hold and then drag outside the cell, the cell should have no highlight). Can you verify it?

Comment: you were almost there. The correct method is not `setHighlighted` but `setSelected`.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had two buttons in my `UITableViewCell` whose background colors were being cleared. These buttons were of type `GrayButton`, a custom class I wrote that derives `UIButton`. Rather than override `UITableViewCell` methods, I instead overrode `GrayButton`'s `setBackgroundColor:` method:

```
- (void)setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor
{
    if (backgroundColor != [UIColor clearColor]) {
        [super setBackgroundColor:backgroundColor];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I switched to the contentView and it works much better

```
UIColor *backgroundColor = selected ? [UIColor redColor] : [UIColor clearColor];
self.contentView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
```

instead of replacing the selectedBackgroundView

```
UIView *selectionColor = [[UIView alloc] init];
selectionColor.backgroundColor = selected ? [UIColor redColor] : [UIColor clearColor];;
self.selectedBackgroundView = selectionColor;
[selectionColor release];
```

now the issue is only visible if the cell you tap and start scroll from is not the selected cell.