# How can I get UITableViewCell to call setHighlighted or setSelected on custom UIView subclass?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview

`UITableViewCell` [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468449/the-selectedbackgroundview-modifies-the-contentview-subviews) [calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33833117/how-can-i-get-uitableviewcell-to-call-setselected-on-custom-uiview-subclass) `setHighlighted:` and `setSelected:` on eligible subviews (`UIImageView`, `UILabel`, etc) when it gets selected. Say I have a custom `UIView` subclass that I have in a cell, and I want it to get the same calls. I've implemented `setHighlighted:` and `setSelected:` on it, but no call comes. Is there some interface I have to declare conformance to? Or am I going to have to use a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell`, override `setSelected:`, and walk through my subviews myself?

It seems weird that they wouldn't just walk the subviews and ask each one if it responds to `setSelected:` and/or `setHighlighted:`.

Answer (score 0):

Create subclass of `UITableViewCell` (if you use storyboards, add your custom `UIView` and add `@IBOutlet`). Override `setSelected` in your subclass of `UITableViewCell`:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

     @IBOutlet weak var customView: CustomView!

     //Other methods and properties


         override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
             super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
             customView.setSelected(selected)
         }
}
```

Comment: I'm hoping to avoid having to make the cell talk explicitly to its special subview(s). My goal is to get the cell to treat my custom view the same way it does any other selectable subview.

Comment: OK, I think your only chance is to set explicitly:
`cell.selectionStyle = .Gray`. Or any other selectionStyle.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Source Code](http://developer.limneos.net/?framework=UIKit.framework&header=UITableViewCell.h) helped. After some trial and error you need to include the following pieces:

```
@property (assign,getter=isHighlighted,nonatomic) BOOL highlighted;

- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted ;
- (BOOL)isHighlighted;
```

Once added, my custom UIView received the cell highlighted events.

Good Luck!