# How can I prevent blue highlight when select row from tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = YES

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view and custom TableViewCell with configure to allow multiple cell to be selected in editing mode and a check-mark will showing when I selected cell.

```
tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = YES
```

I want to prevent the blue highlight when I selected my cell in editing mode.

I have try many ways like configure cell selection style but with this configure the "check-mark" won't be show in editing mode when cell selected.

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

I really need helps in this case. Thanks.

Comment: you could set a custom highlight color to be a clear color

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog how can I do that ?

Answer (score 3):

You can overwrite the selectedBackgroundView property of your custom tableViewCell 
this line of code works for me

```
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)]];
```

Answer (score 2):

One method is to overwrite `setHighlighted:animated:` in your cell:

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated {
    // do nothing
}
```

This will block the highlighting behavior, not the selection behavior. The selection can be completely overriden using:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    // update UI for selection state
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift:

`cell.selectedBackgroundView = UIView(frame: cell.frame)` or

`cell.selectedBackgroundView.isHidden = true`

But it may still not work as you expect. When selected all of the cell's subviews' backgroundColor to clear color(transparent), you may want to [recover it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469974/3301515)